# Taking in a $3\times3$ matrix and then graphing its vectors

Tags: graphics3d, linear-algebra

I am trying to graph various vectors of a $3\times3$ matrix to make a box by writing a function that takes in a $3\times3$ matrix and then plots the polygons created from it. Let the 3 column vectors be $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{C}$, then for example one face of the box is given by the polygon

```
P1 = Polygon[O, A, A + B, B]
```

where `O` is the origin. There are 5 additional polygons that make up the surface of the box; however, I can't figure out how to set up function correctly. Here is my code so far:

```
plotBox[{ {a_, b_, c_}, {d_, e_, f_ }, {g_, h_, i_} }] := 
P1 = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, d, g}, {a + b, d + e, g + h}, {b, e, 
h}}]    
Graphics3D[{P1}]
```

Now if I call `plotBox` and pass it a $3\times3$ matrix, it will simply output the `Polygon` that was created. However, if I go to where I actually wrote the function and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then it will `Graphics3D` the `plotBox` I entered in. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code was that you got `P1` in there with your function definition.

```
plotBox[{{a_, b_, c_}, {d_, e_, f_}, {g_, h_, i_}}] := 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, d, g}, {a + b, d + e, g + h}, {b, e, h}}]
```

will work to get you one of the polygons.

For a more general function to get all six polygons, you can do

```
plotbox[matrix_] := With[{trmat = Transpose @ matrix}, 
  Polygon /@ 
   Transpose[
    {#, Total @ trmat - #} & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, #1, #1 + #2, #2}
   ] & @@@ Subsets[trmat, {2}]
 ]
```

Then

```
m = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
p1 = plotbox[m];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 0, 0}, Total @ Transpose @ m}], p1}]
```

[image]

**A brief explanation**

`plotbox` might not be particularly intuitive to read, but it actually breaks down quite simply. First, suppose that our matrix is

```
matrix = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
```

Then `trmat = Transpose @ matrix` just gives a list of the column vectors (if you want to plot the row vector box, just leave out the `Transpose`), and

```
Subsets[trmat, {2}]

(* { {{a, d, g}, {b, e, h}}, 
     {{a, d, g}, {c, f, i}}, 
     {{b, e, h}, {c, f, i}} } *)
```

gives all the vector pairs. Each pair is used to construct two polygons. The vertices for one polygon from the first pair are

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {a, d, g}, {a + b, d + e, g + h}, {b, e, h}}
```

(as in the OP's original function). The second set of vertices are these same points subtracted from the total of all the column vectors of `matrix`:

```
Total @ trmat (* or Total /@ matrix *)

(* {a + b + c, d + e + f, g + h + i} *)
```

Then `plotbox` sets up the pure function

```
Transpose[{#, Total @ trmat - #} & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, #1, #1 + #2, #2}] &
```

which, when applied to a pair of points in `Subsets[trmat, {2}]` (corresponding to the slots `#1` and `#2`), gives the vertices of the two polygons derived from that pair. The `@@@` simply [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)s the function to each pair, giving a list of polygon vertices. `Polygon /@` then turns these vertices into actual polygons.

Comment: Here's another possible implementation: `plotbox[matrix_?MatrixQ] := With[{trmat = Transpose[matrix]}, Polygon /@ Flatten[Transpose[{#, 1 - #} & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, #1, #1 + #2, #2}].trmat & @@@ Subsets[IdentityMatrix[3], {2}], 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

If a visualization is all that's wanted, use `Parallelepiped[]`:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[128]; (* for reproducibility *)
            Graphics3D[Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, Transpose[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]]]]
```

[image: random parallelepiped]

(Compare with the result of `Graphics3D[plotbox[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]]` as in aardvark's answer.)

If you really need the polygons, you can start with `PolyhedronData["Cube"]` instead:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[128]; 
            MapAt[(# + 1/2).Transpose[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]] &, 
                  PolyhedronData["Cube", "GraphicsComplex"], {1}] // Normal]
   {{Polygon[{{1.65941, 1.11438, 1.2699}, {0.872272, 0.730417, 1.00725},
              {0.0192757, 0.71586, 0.166596}, {0.80641, 1.09982, 0.429248}}], 
     Polygon[{{1.65941, 1.11438, 1.2699}, {0.80641, 1.09982, 0.429248},
              {0.787135, 0.383961, 0.262652}, {1.64013, 0.398517, 1.1033}}], 
     Polygon[{{1.65941, 1.11438, 1.2699}, {1.64013, 0.398517, 1.1033},
              {0.852996, 0.0145563, 0.840653}, {0.872272, 0.730417, 1.00725}}], 
     Polygon[{{0.872272, 0.730417, 1.00725}, {0.852996, 0.0145563, 0.840653},
              {0., 0., 0.}, {0.0192757, 0.71586, 0.166596}}], 
     Polygon[{{0., 0., 0.}, {0.852996, 0.0145563, 0.840653},
              {1.64013, 0.398517, 1.1033}, {0.787135, 0.383961, 0.262652}}], 
     Polygon[{{0.0192757, 0.71586, 0.166596}, {0., 0., 0.},
              {0.787135, 0.383961, 0.262652}, {0.80641, 1.09982, 0.429248}}]}}
```

and then evaluating `Graphics3D[%]` should yield the expected picture.